# How to detect keystrokes in Swift on Linux?

Tags: linux, swift, raspberry-pi

I am writing a command line application in Swift that will run on Linux. I want to know what keys the user is touching in real time so I can show a value associated with each key.

Is there a a non blocking way of capturing user keystroke events in real time one key at a time?

I know of the readLine() function but that captures whole words and is blocking.

Anybody knows of a working solution?

Comment: Are there any bindings of: **curses** or **libinput** or **xinput** or **any other Input or GUI toolkit**

Comment: @JakubKaszycki I am only importing Glibc and Foundation. There are no other dependencies in my project for now. But if you know of a library that could handle my problem, that would be useful.

Comment: http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/ncurses-with-swift-on-linux/

Comment: you should take a look at FileHandle.standardInput.readInBackgroundAndNotify() [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilehandle/1417635-readinbackgroundandnotify?language=objc) seems to be your best bet

Answer (score 0):

If you know which input device (for example a USB keyboard) you want to read the real time keystrokes from, then you could use something like: https://github.com/Dev1an/InputEvents

It does not use standard command line input streams but reads the events directly from `/dev/input/...` devices instead.